# Python Function- Return Value is 'not defined'

Tags: function, python-3.x, encryption, return-value

For my encryption code, I am trying to a return a value from one function because it is used in the next. I keep getting an error, telling me that the name 'cipher_text' is not defined. Please help!

Error:

(line 7)

decryption (cipher_text, shift)

NameError: name 'cipher_text' is not defined

```
def main():
    user_input = input ("Enter string: ")
    shift = int(input ("Enter a shift that is between 1 and 26: "))
    while shift<1 or shift>26:
        shift = input ("ERROR: Shift must be between 1 and 26: ")
    encryption (user_input, shift)
    decryption (cipher_text, shift)
    frequency (user_input)

def frequency(user_input): 
    freq_char = None
    for char in user_input: 
        charcount = user_input.count(char) 
        if (charcount != 0): 
            freq_char = char
    print (freq_char)
    return fre_char

def encryption(user_input, shift):
    cipher_text = ''
    for char in user_input: #for every character in input
        if char == ' ':
            cipher = char
            cipher_text += cipher
        else:
            cipher_num = (ord(char))+(shift)%26 #using ordinal to find the number
            cipher= ''
            cipher = chr(cipher_num)# using chr to convert back to a letter
            cipher_text += cipher
    print ("The encrypted text is:",cipher_text)
    return(cipher_text)


def decryption (cipher_text, shift):
    decrypt_text = ''
    cipher_text = ''
    for char in cipher_text: #for every character in the encrpted text
        decrypt_num = (ord(char))+(int(shift))%26
        decrypt= ''
        decrypt = chr(decrypt_num)
        decrypt_text += decrypt
    print("The decrypted text is:", decrypt_text)
    return(decrypt_text)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the lines

```
    encryption (user_input, shift)
    decryption (cipher_text, shift)
```

as the exception tells you.  If you had included the traceback with your question this would be very clear.

Variables you declare in one function are local to that function.  This is a good thing!  It lets you write functions like

```
def foo():
    x = 1
    return x * x

def bar():
    for x in xrange(10):
        print "Count: %s" % x
```

without them blowing each other up.

If you call a function that returns something and you want to use it, you need to use it directly, or assign it to something:

```
# assign
x = foo()
print x
# use directly
print "x is %s" % foo()
```

in your case, you can make a minimal change to assign the result of `encryption` to a new variable `cipher_text`

```
def main():
      ...
    cipher_text = encryption(user_input, shift)
    decryption(cipher_text, shift)
```

it would be equivalent (though less clear) to call this anything else

```
    foobar = encryption(user_input, shift)
    decryption(foobar, shift)
```

or even to avoid use of a variable altogether

```
    decryption(encryption(user_input, shift), shift)
```

Comment: `decryption` should return something.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I wasn't attempting to provide a code review, rather to help explain his problem.  In this case, his function would still print something, and he doesn't use the return, so I avoided complicating the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

`def main()` should be `def main(cipher_text)`
You can also set a default value for `cipeher_text`:

```
def main(cipher_text=""):
    user_input = input ("Enter string: ")
    shift = int(input ("Enter a shift that is between 1 and 26: "))
    while shift<1 or shift>26:
        shift = input ("ERROR: Shift must be between 1 and 26: ")
    encryption (user_input, shift)
    decryption (cipher_text, shift)
    frequency (user_input)
```

And then just call `main()` using a value example `main('some value')` or just empty if you defined a default value as said before.

Comment: that actually doesnt work! The error is no longer given, but the decryption function becomes useless.

Comment: In some way you have to define cipeher_text or not use it at all. You can't use something that doesn't exist.

Comment: As I said `def main(cipher_text="")` is optional, you can use main(cipher_text) or leave it blank and define it inside the function

Comment: Also, in the decryption function you are replacing any value passed to the function by an empty string

Comment: If you define a variable inside a function then don't define it in the arguments, and vice versa